# Receiving Error in R when running dev.off()

Tags: r

I repeatedly receive this Error.

Error in http://dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)

What is the problem?

Comment: I've never seen `http://dev.off()` in any error message in R (and I've run, debugged, and crashed: base R graphics, grid graphics, 3d graphics, plotly, etc). Can you provide some context on how you triggered that error? (Specifically, `http://` seems odd in this context.)

Comment: You should add a full reproducible example. Try using the `reprex` R package.

Comment: I run this on R Studio

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the following statement:`if(dev.cur() > 1) dev.off()`

Answer (score 0):

You should have a previous plot, otherwise you will receive an error

```
plot(1)

dev.off()
null device 
          1
#Once the graphics device is shutted down...
dev.off()
Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)
```